# "RuntimeError: Working outside of application context" in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am learning flask using this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Z1RJmh_OqeA?t=1227). When I try to execute `db.create_all()` in the interactive python environment in VS Code, I get `Working outside of application context` error. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65767324/12526953) solution, I have done everything correct. I am not able to find the error in my code. Can someone please help me?
Following is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    completed = db.Column(db.Integer, default =0)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The interactive python steps:

1. `from app import db`
2. `db.create_all()`

The folder structure looks like:

[image]

Comment: could you show `interactive python` steps?

Comment: @ Danila Ganchar, I have updated my question with the interactive python steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need [to push application context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context).

```
# debug.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
# change sqlalchemy log level
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

from console:

```
Python 3.10.4 (main, Jun 29 2022, 12:14:53) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from debug import app, db
../env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
>>> with app.app_context():
...     db.create_all()  # you work inside app context
... 
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:PRAGMA main.table_info("todo")
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] ()
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Col ('cid', 'name', 'type', 'notnull', 'dflt_value', 'pk')
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:PRAGMA temp.table_info("todo")
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] ()
DEBUG:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:Col ('cid', 'name', 'type', 'notnull', 'dflt_value', 'pk')
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:
CREATE TABLE todo (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[no key 0.00007s] ()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:COMMIT
```

Comment: When `db.create_all()` is executed it is supposed to create `test.py` under `app.py`. But `test.db` is not created. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @Aim what mean `test.py`?

Comment: There is a typo in my comment: I meant `test.db` from `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'`

Comment: @Aim are you sure that you run `python terminal` from project directory? hm... try to check `write` access to directory. JFYI: this should work fine